# Finding Grad of G,

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, chain-rule, scalar-fields

OK, so I'm out of ideas. The question is:
Let  f(x,y) be a function with continous partial derivatives that upholds:

$$
\bigtriangledown f (0,-8) = (-3\widehat{i}, 5\widehat{j})
$$
let g(x,y) be the function :
$$
g(x,y) = f(xy+x^2 , xy-y^2)
$$

Calculate: (a Vector)
$$
\bigtriangledown g(-2,2) = ?
$$

**My take on this:**
$$
\bigtriangledown g = \left(\frac{\partial \:g}{\partial \:x},\:\frac{\partial \:g}{\partial \:y}\right)
$$
let u,v be:
$$
u\left(x,y\right)\:=\:xy+x^2\:\:,\:v\left(x,y\right)\:=\:xy-y^{2\:}
$$

and then By the chain Rule:
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\:=\:\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\:\cdot \:\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\:+\:\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\cdot \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\:=\:\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\:\cdot \:\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\:+\:\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\cdot \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
$$

Placing du/dx du/dy and dv/dx dv/dy , and evaluating at the point (-2,2)
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\:=\:+2\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\:+6\:\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\:=\:+2\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\:-2\:\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}
$$
My question is how to procceed further?, What do i do with The partial derivatives of g with respect to u and v.

Comment: Solved. Thanks, I will Post a detailed answer soon :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that you could use the chain rule on its matrix form. Let

$$h(x,y)=(xy+x^2, xy-y^2)$$

and observe that $h(-2, 2)=(0,-8)$. Now $g(x,y)=(f \circ h)(x,y)$ and according to the chain rule

$$(\nabla (f \circ h)(x,y))^T = (\nabla f(h(x,y))^T J_h (x,y).$$

So we get

\begin{align}
(\nabla (f \circ h)(-2,2))^T &= (\nabla f(0,-8))^T J_h (-2,2) \\
&= [-3 \quad 5] \begin{bmatrix} -2 & -2 \\
2 & -6 
\end{bmatrix} = [16 \quad -24]
\end{align}

Now, I don't think this is the most elegant way of using the chain rule here, so I would like to see other solutions.